# ComboBOX qual melhor método: OnSelectedIndexChanged via autopostback ou Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

Tenho o seguinte DropDownList em asp.net Webform

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Categoria" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True">Selecione</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Ao selecionar esse campo, automáticamente um outro DropDownList deve ser completado no rodapé do formulário.
Qual melhor método? Mais rápido, politicamente correto?

---

**Método 01**

Code Behind + autopostback

```
<asp:DropDownList ... OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_Categoria_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
```

e no code-behind faço a lógica.
Desvantagem: Ele carrega a página, se ele estiver digitando em outro campo pode causar algum atraso?

---

**Método 02:**

Javascript chamando em iframe. Criaria uma nova página .aspx para receber esse valor

```
<asp:DropDownList ... onchange="nome_functionJS(this.value)"
    <script>
    function nome_functionJS(valor){
document.getElementById("IFRAMEID").src ='monta_DDL.aspx?value=' + valor
}
```

---

**Método 03:**
Jquery (não faço nem ideia como chamar)

Comment: Com codebehind vc pode usar o UpdatePanel com triggers para atualizar um outro update panel embaixo.

Com jquery, vc pode fazer a chamada vida ajax e retornar uma lista para inserir nesse novo combro

Comment: updatepanel não gosto de utilizar é o ajax component do webform né? acho meio arcaico e sei lá..rs
Acho que a melhor forma é javascript pois não interfere no formulário o mais rápido é codebehind, mas da um refresh na tela, perdendo o foco do campo do usuário, um dia que a internet não estiver boa pode ser bem chato..então por isso queria saber como o pessoal com mais experiencia recomenda.

Comment: Só o fato ainda do `webforms` também pode ser chamado de `arcaico` e o `UpdatePanel` é um ajax feito especificamente e preparado de maneira útil para o WebForms

Comment: Sobre perder o foco após refresh via codebehind, existem várias formas de resolver o problema. Por exemplo, você pode dar um ".focus()" no controle. Ou então incluir "#+algum-id-qualquer" na action do botão ou do formulário. Ou seja, perder o foco não é problema. Em webform o problema é sempre o "bendito" refresh. Eu não gosto de refresh na tela ao mudar um controle. Eu usaria ajax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solução utilizando UpdatePanel**

Utilizando-se UpdatePanel, permite-se uma manutenção mais fácil do aplicativo pois evita-se o uso de javascript.

Além disso, quanto ao problema da digitação, basta colocar UpdatePanels individuais em cada dropdownlist e controlar a autalização dos mesmos, sem interferir no resto da página.

Uma desvantagem é que ele faz uma request com todas as informações da página, mesmo não sendo necessárias. Contudo, a atualização da mesa é feita apenas nos UpdatePanels atualizados. Para páginas de pequeno e médio porte isso não é um problema.

Trabalhando-se com ASP.NET acho essa a melhor solução pois já é integrada ao framework é dificilmente se encontram casos em que realmente há problemas de performance.

A seguir é mostrado um bom tutorial de como se trabalhar com UpdatePanel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.100).aspx

**Solução utilizando jquery/ajax**

Para desenvolvedores que utilizam essa tecnolgia rotineiramente, provavelmente é mais fácil trabalhar com javascript do que entender todo o mecanismo de funcioamento do UpdatePanel. O grande problema é entender como funcionam dropdownlists juntamente com javascript. Deve-se tomar muito cuidado para interagir com os elementos certos do componente via javascript.

Uma sugestão é: trate os controles como elementos HTML para que sua manipuação via javascript seja fácil. Caso se precise acessá-los no code-behind, coloque im Id nesses componentes HTML juntamente com a tag runat="server". Daí, é possível recuperá-los no code-behind via método `FindControl("IdDoContolador");`.